# Unallocated space doesn't show in ubuntu installation (dual boot/ two drives)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have an ssd and an hdd and want to use them for windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04. I'm planning on using the ssd for /, /boot and swap and the hdd for /home. I have partitioned my drive as showing in [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYFJY.png). While the unallocated space from the ssd (38GB) is visible during the installation partitioning, the hdd unallocated space (200GB) is nowhere to be found. All there is is one partition of 950GB (which is the whole drive). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You activated the dynamic disks in Windows, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing. My notebook has a 128GB SSD and 1 TB Hard drive. After installing Windows on the SSD and Ubuntu on 200GB of my 1 TB drive I had the same issue with the non partitioned space. I went in to ubuntu and installed Gparted from the software center. I used Gparted to partition and format the free space in NTFS and I can now read and write from both Windows and Ubuntu.